# How to avoid unwanted Mouse Scroll Event and execute code after a delay

Tags: java, swt

Please check the below snippet

```
dashboard.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {          
            @Override
            public void mouseScrolled(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                //doSomething
            }
        });
```

This will trigger mouseEvent on Scroll. The problem is this will trigger the event more than 10 times for single scroll.

1, How to get the last event only, after 1 sec delay. Tried to figure out using Timer and ScheduledExecutorService, but couldn't get the fix.

2, Also after 1 sec if I scroll again it should work

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this

```
private ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;
dashboard.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {          
   @Override
   public void mouseScrolled(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    //for canceling previously scheduled.
    if(scheduledFuture != null)
        scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
    scheduledFuture  = executor.schedule(task, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);    
   }
});

dashboard.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {    
  @Override
  public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent arg0) {
    executor.shutdownNow();                         
  }
});

 Callable task = () -> {                
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
      //do something
    });                                                         
 return null;
 };
```